# What to parameter value from returning url in php

Tags: php, jquery

I have a client url[www.mysite.com/page.aspx]

when we put this url in browser then it revert the automatically
with this url

> [www.mysite.com/page.aspx?|&CC=121&DD=123&AA=323|&CC=321&DD=555&AA=000]

Now we want to fetch that parameter value in php page through php or jquery.

Kindly Help and give the best suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use GET

```
$cc = $_GET['CC'];
$dd = $_GET['DD'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access those values using `$_REQUEST` or `$_GET`